# Code Generation Utility in C#/VB .Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, c#-4.0

I am using C# to develop an enterprise level application. I use VS2010 Modeling Project to model my classes but there is no code generation utility which available for free.
I want to know if is there any Utility/Extension that can generate C#/VB code from UML diagrams.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [T4 framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) does comprehensive code generation in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks to Reply Tom. Your Provided Link is About T4 Code Template Which uses many ways to Generate code but not from UML Diagrams. My need is to Generate Code From UML Diagrams Particularly Class Diagrams. Can You Help me in Scenario.

Comment: You can generate code from anything you like if you're willing to write the template logic. Alternatively, thirty seconds on google yielded the following http://www.olegsych.com/2010/01/uml-modeling-and-code-generation-in-visual-studio-2010/ which looks like what you're asking for. It mentions code generation from the VS2010 UML diagrams, which apears to be built-in.